# Cauchy principal value for strong oscillating function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm interested in the following: Suppose I have a sufficiently smooth function $f(t)$
and consider the integral
$$
\int_{k-\epsilon}^{k+\epsilon} f(t) \, \cot(\pi t) \, {\rm d}t
$$
for some $\epsilon>0$ and $k \in {\mathbb N}$. If the function is smooth enough typically the pole is canceled as in the PrincipalValue. But what if the function is highly oscillatory like the following
$$
\int_{k-\epsilon}^{k+\epsilon} \cos^2(N\pi t) \, \cot(\pi t) \, {\rm d}t
$$
and we consider the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$. Can anything be said about the behaviour of this ?

I was thinking about the following

$$
\int_{k-\epsilon}^{k+\epsilon} \cos^2(N\pi t) \, \cot(\pi t) \, {\rm d}t \\
\approx \int_{k-\epsilon}^{k+\epsilon} \frac{\cos^2(N\pi t)}{\pi(t-k)} \, {\rm d}t \\
= -\frac{1}{\pi} \, \sin(2\pi Nk) \, {\rm Si}(2\pi N \epsilon) \\
= -\frac{\sin(2\pi Nk)}{2} + {\cal O}\left(1/N\right)
$$
and I assumed $\epsilon N >> 1$.

Can statements about this made rigorously under general circumstances?

Thanks

Comment: Like $$1-\frac{2}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{2}}\right)} \, ?$$

Answer (score 0):

What if $f(t)$ is piecewise constant such that
$$f(t)=2^{-n} (n-1/2\leq t<n+1/2) $$
(with $f(t)=1$ only on $[0,1/2]$). Clearly the integral of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is finite but it already seems to be that
$$\int_0^1 f(t)\tan(\pi t)\,dt$$
is divergent.

Comment: assuming diferentiability?